# Spring Message japanese characters from a resource bundle display as "?"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, utf-8, internationalization

I'm using Spring MVC / Message to translate a java properties file in my application.  All language are rendering correctly (except Japanese and Chinese.. They both appear as '?' question marks) The resulting page has a proper UTF-8 encoding.. Is it required to install a language pack to see the characters in the browser or am I encountering some other encoding issue?

I'm using this declaration for charset

They appear in my IDE / Text editors correctly on the same machine.

any thanks appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your response have the right Content header set?  For example:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

You say that the page has a proper UTF-8 encoding, but it's worth verifying.  Next I would check the encoding of the properties files themselves.  They might not be saved in UTF-8.

Also, no, you don't need a language pack to see chinese/japanese characters in a browser.  As a sanity check you could google "chinese newspaper" and make sure you can see other chinese pages.

Comment: The content header was correct. But the ReloadableResource from Spring needed a charset -- helpful - http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/2009/04/02/utf-8-encoding-and-message-sources/